# How do I upload an updated JAR to an existing Java Elastic Beanstalk instance using the AWS CLI 2?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I have a Java Elastic Beanstalk instance set up manually through the web UI.

I can upload an updated JAR to it any time manually through the UI.

How do I accomplish the same via the AWS CLI 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use maven to build my JAR.

```
mvn clean install
```

This generates the JAR `my-app.jar` in the `./target` directory.

I then do the following

```
export version=1.0-`date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"`
```

This is an environment variable I'll use throughout the process.

Step 1. Upload the JAR to an S3 bucket

```
aws s3 cp ./target/my-app.jar s3://my-app.foo.bar/my-app-${version}.jar
```

Step 2. Create a Version of the Application in Elastic Beanstalk.

This references the JAR uploaded to S3 in Step 1.

```
aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version \
  --application-name my-app \
  --version-label ${version} \
  --source-bundle S3Bucket="my-app.foo.bar",S3Key="my-app-${version}.jar"
```

Step 3. Deploy the Version in Elastic Beanstalk

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment \
  --application-name my-app \
  --environment-name MyApp-env \
  --version-label ${version}
```

The key points to note here are that;

a) You don't deploy a JAR. You deploy a Version. And the Version points to the JAR. This is distinct from (what you see) what you do through the UI, where you just upload the JAR and it gets deployed.

b) The `source-bundle` of the Version points to the JAR. Yes, although in the Java world, the word 'source' means something and a JAR is not source, in the Elastic Beanstalk world, the 'source' is your executable code

c) the JAR the Version points to has to be in S3. *That* is where you upload your JAR.

Answer (score -1):

You do it in **two sets**:

1. Create new application version with your new program using [create-application-version](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/create-application-version.html). Note the `--version-label` for the version that you want to use.
2. Update your EB environment to use the new application version with [update-environment](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/update-environment.html). You will have to provide `--version-label` from step 1.

Alternatively, you can use [AWS EB CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html) which is CLI tool specifically developed by AWS for EB.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, Step one (create-application-version) is fine. In step Two (update-environment), where do I specify the path to the JAR?

Comment: @Vihung You just use `--version-label` to specify which application version label to use.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out. The `--source-bundle` points to the JAR. But it has to be in an S3 Bucket

Comment: @Vihung Ok, so you took my steps, devoted me, and added your own answer based on mine which is basically same  (minus S3)?.

Comment: thanks for the pointers. But it didn't fully answer the question as asked - specifically, how do I upload the JAR. Also, links to documentation help, but also don't answer the specific question.